# I lost my reputation point of about 40. Why?

Tags: support, reputation

Several days ago my reputation point was about 440 in total, but now it becomes 409. I haven't offered any bounty. Where is the missing point now? Could you help me to investigate it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your reputation was recalculated as part of a change made to help keep reputation up-to-date. In the past, reputation gained from votes on posts was not immediately removed if the post was deleted - this should happen much more quickly in the future. For details, see: [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)